# Django orm remove overlapping date_ranges

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm new to django & I have a table with multiple entries of different date_ranges. I want to get only the unique ranges & then get Count of numbers of days from them. For example

Consider following three ranges:

```
1. 10-09-2017 to 10-09-2019
2. 10-08-2018 to 10-02-2020
2. 04-04-2020 to 04-04-2020
```

In the above example 1 & 2 have overlapping dates, actual calculation for point 2 should change `start_range` to the `end_range` of point 1 and then calculate days based on that (I know it can be a little confusing and I'm happy to explain it further if required) I can use something like following to get difference in days for each date_range

```
calculate_experience = ExpressionWrapper(
        Case(
            When(experiences__end__isnull=True, then=date.today()-F('start'))[0].days, default=F('end')-F('start')),
            distinct=True, filter=Q(is_active=True), output_field=DurationField()
    )
```

But I have no idea how to get only unique ranges from this, the only thing that comes to mind is putting these in a list & then iterating over that manually settings ranges & then calculating the difference. Is there a better way to do this? Any help or sense of direction is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this example I execute two queries that grab users from the database. Then I use [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to find which users are in both sets.

If I understand correctly this should answer the question of overlapping days between range 1 and range 2.

```
some_users = User.objects.filter(id__gt=3)
>>> some_users <QuerySet [<User: cake>, <User: pie>]>

all_users = User.objects.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<User: admin>, <User: apple>, <User: banana>, <User: cake>, <User: pie>]>

# Casting to set is optional. 
some_users_set = set(some_users)
all_users_set = set(all_users)

# users in both sets
some_users_set & all_users_set
>>> {<User: cake>, <User: pie>}
```